# TypeConverter for dependent properties - show list of methods of the selected type in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am working on a new solution of N layers (entities, data, business and presentation) and I need to create a custom control to speed up the searches (the control will be in the presentation layer).

Here the structure of the solution:

```
Solution
Ⱶ Entities
  Ⱶ customer__entity
  Ⱶ user__entity
  Ⱶ product__entity
Ⱶ Data
  Ⱶ customer__data
  Ⱶ user__data
  Ⱶ product__data
Ⱶ Business
  Ⱶ customer__business
  Ⱶ user__business
  Ⱶ product__business
Ⱶ Presentation
  Ⱶ controls (folder)
    Ⱶ TextSearch (custom control)
  Ⱶ forms (folder)
    Ⱶ frm__customer___maintenance
    Ⱶ frm__user___maintenance
    Ⱶ frm__product___maintenance
```

Now I will detail the methods that the classes of the business layer have.

```
public abstract class customer__business
{
    public static IEnumerable<customer__entity> GetAll() { }
    public static customer__entity GetById(int id) { }
}

public abstract class user__business
{
    public static IEnumerable<customer__entity> GetAllByCriteria(string criteria) { }
    public static customer__entity GetById(int id) { }
    public static DataTable GetBy(string criteria) { }
}

public abstract class product__business
{
    public static product__entity GetById(int id) { }
    public static string GetName(string criteria) { }
}
```

The idea is to create a TextBox control that inherits from System.Windows.Forms.TextBox and has 2 custom properties (1 => BusinessLayer and 2 => MethodToInvoke). The first property will be of type type and will use TypeConverter to load the business layer classes. The second property will depend on the first, and it must list all the methods that the type selected in the first property has.

```
public class TextSearch : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
{
    [TypeConverter(typeof(BusinessLayerTypeConverter))]
    public Type BusinessLayer { get; set; }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(MethodToInvokeTypeConverter))]
    public string MethodToInvoke { get; set; }
}
```

I already have the Business Layer TypeConverter class ready:

```
public class BusinessLayerTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext pContext, Type pDestinationType)
    {
        return base.CanConvertTo(pContext, pDestinationType);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext pContext, CultureInfo pCulture, object pValue, Type pDestinationType)
    {
        return base.ConvertTo(pContext, pCulture, pValue, pDestinationType);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext pContext, Type pSourceType)
    {
        if (pSourceType == typeof(string))
            return true;

        return base.CanConvertFrom(pContext, pSourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext pContext, CultureInfo pCulture, object pValue)
    {
        if (pValue is string)
            return GetTypeFromName(pContext, (string)pValue);

        return base.ConvertFrom(pContext, pCulture, pValue);
    }

    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext pContext)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext pContext)
    {
        List<Type> types = GetProjectTypes(pContext);
        List<string> values = new List<string>();

        foreach (Type type in types)
            values.Add(type.FullName);

        values.Sort();

        return new StandardValuesCollection(values);
    }

    private List<Type> GetProjectTypes(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var typeDiscoverySvc = (ITypeDiscoveryService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITypeDiscoveryService));
        var types = typeDiscoverySvc.GetTypes(typeof(object), true).Cast<Type>().Where(item => item.IsPublic && !item.FullName.StartsWith("System") && item.FullName.Contains("__business")).ToList();

        return types;
    }

    private Type GetTypeFromName(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, string typeName)
    {
        ITypeResolutionService typeResolutionSvc = (ITypeResolutionService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITypeResolutionService));

        return typeResolutionSvc.GetType(typeName);
    }
}
```

This is the result of the first property and it works correctly.

[image]

My problem is that I don't know what to do so that the second property (MethodToInvoke) lists the methods of the type selected in the first property (BusinessLayer).

> 1. If BusinessLayer property is Business.customer__business then MethodToInvoke should allow me to select GetAll or GetById.
> 2. If BusinessLayer property is Business.user__business then MethodToInvoke should allow me to select GetAllByCriteria or GetById or GetBy.
> 3. If BusinessLayer property is Business.product__business then MethodToInvoke should allow me to select GetById or GetName.

This is the class MethodToInvokeTypeConverter:

```
public class MethodToInvokeTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext pContext, Type pDestinationType)
    {
        return base.CanConvertTo(pContext, pDestinationType);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext pContext, CultureInfo pCulture, object pValue, Type pDestinationType)
    {
        return base.ConvertTo(pContext, pCulture, pValue, pDestinationType);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext pContext, Type pSourceType)
    {
        if (pSourceType == typeof(string))
            return true;

        return base.CanConvertFrom(pContext, pSourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext pContext, CultureInfo pCulture, object pValue)
    {
        if (pValue is string)
            return GetTypeFromName(pContext, (string)pValue);

        return base.ConvertFrom(pContext, pCulture, pValue);
    }

    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext pContext)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext pContext)
    {
        List<Type> types = GetProjectTypes(pContext);
        List<string> values = new List<string>();

        foreach (Type type in types)
            values.Add(type.FullName);

        values.Sort();

        return new StandardValuesCollection(values);
    }

    private List<Type> GetProjectTypes(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var types = // I SUPPOSE THAT I SHOULD CODE WHAT I NEED HERE, HOWEVER I DON'T KNOW WHERE TO START.

        return types;
    }

    private Type GetTypeFromName(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, string typeName)
    {
        ITypeResolutionService typeResolutionSvc = (ITypeResolutionService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITypeResolutionService));

        return typeResolutionSvc.GetType(typeName);
    }
}
```

Thanks for all the help you can give me.

EDIT 1:

The idea of the control is that when adding the control to a form the programmer will set the BusinessLayer property (which will be loaded automatically from the existing classes in the business layer), then set the MethodToInvoke property (which will be loaded automatically with the existing methods of the type selected in the BusinessLayer property).

In the TextSearch control I will overwrite the KeyDown method to by means of reflection invoke the method of the type selected in the properties respectively (MethodToInvoke, BusinessLayer).

```
public class TextSearch : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
{
    [TypeConverter(typeof(BusinessLayerTypeConverter))]
    public Type BusinessLayer { get; set; }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(MethodToInvokeTypeConverter))]
    public string MethodToInvoke { get; set; }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);

        if (!DesignMode)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                var type = BusinessLayer;
                var method = MethodToInvoke;

                type.GetMethod(method).Invoke(null, null);

                // CODE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Just creating a search-control that searches thru a list of objects? Have properties appear in the winforms designer? What are these properties actually supposed to be doing?

Comment: MethodToInvoke is a string, in your GetProjectTypes you should iterate with reflection the class type that you need and return the name of method in your converter... but is only a string ;)

Comment: The problem is in the MethodToInvokeTypeConverter class, I don't know how to list the methods according to the type selected in the BusinessLayer property. I suppose that in the GetProjectTypes (ITypeDescriptorContext pContext) method I must capture the value of BusinessLayer but I don't know how to do it (and with reflection list all the methods of the type.) I edit my post (read please the final part).

Comment: @pedroPG The question is for a few month ago (at the time of writing this comment) and you most like have found a solution for that yourself, but the topic and the question is an interesting one, so I answered the question and shared an example along with some links for future readers to learn more on this topic. Hope you and the future readers find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, what you need to do is:

1. In your control, in the master property (business class type), when the value changes, set the slave property (method name) to null or any other meaningful value.
2. In the slave property type converter, in [`GetStandardValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.getstandardvalues?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), cast the [`context.Instnace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.itypedescriptorcontext.instance?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=net-6.0) to your control type and then get the value of the master property (business class type) and return list of possible values (method names).

That's all. Above comments will solve your problem, but you or the future readers may find the following example interesting.

**Example - Property editor to choose a class and one of its methods**

Here in this example, I've created a custom control which has two new properties:

- `BusinessClassType`: For this property I use a custom type converter to show a list of business classes.
- `MethodName`: For this property I use a custom type converter to show a list of business methods.

Instead of relying on naming conventions to find business classes, I created an attribute `BusinessClass`; Also for methods, I created `BusinessMethod` attribute, so I do not show all the methods in the dropdown, just those that you mark as business method. It's somehow similar to the idea in WFC service contracts and method contracts.

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

```
public class MyCustomControl : TextBox
{
    private Type type;
    [TypeConverter(typeof(BusinessClassTypeConverter))]
    public Type BusinessClassType
    {
        get { return type; }
        set
        {
            if (type != value)
            {
                type = value;
                BusinessMethodName = null;
            }
        }
    }
    [TypeConverter(typeof(BusinessMethodNameConverter))]
    public string BusinessMethodName { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class BusinessClassTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive
        (ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported
        (ITypeDescriptorContext pContext)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues
        (ITypeDescriptorContext pContext)
    {
        return new StandardValuesCollection(
            GetProjectTypes(pContext).OrderBy(x => x.FullName).ToList());
    }
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
        Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
            return true;
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }
    public override object ConvertFrom
        (ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
            return GetTypeFromName(context, (string)value);
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
        Type destinationType)
    {
        return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
        CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
    private List<Type> GetProjectTypes(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var typeDiscoverySvc = (ITypeDiscoveryService)serviceProvider
            .GetService(typeof(ITypeDiscoveryService));
        var types = typeDiscoverySvc.GetTypes(typeof(object), true)
            .Cast<Type>()
            .Where(item =>
                item.IsPublic &&
                item.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                .OfType<BusinessClassAttribute>().Any() &&
                !item.FullName.StartsWith("System")
            ).ToList();
        return types;
    }
    private Type GetTypeFromName(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, string typeName)
    {
        ITypeResolutionService typeResolutionSvc = 
            (ITypeResolutionService)serviceProvider
            .GetService(typeof(ITypeResolutionService));
        return typeResolutionSvc.GetType(typeName);
    }
}
```

```
public class BusinessMethodNameConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(
        ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(
        ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(
        ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        var type = ((MyCustomControl)context.Instance).BusinessClassType;
        if (type != null)
        {
            return new StandardValuesCollection(type.GetMethods()
                .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                .OfType<BusinessMethodAttribute>().Any())
                .Select(x => x.Name).ToList());
        }
        return new StandardValuesCollection(Array.Empty<object>());
    }
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
        Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
            return true;
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
        CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
            return (string)value;
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

```
public class BusinessClassAttribute : Attribute { }
public class BusinessMethodAttribute : Attribute { }

[BusinessClass]
public class MyBusinessClass1
{
    [BusinessMethod]
    public void Method11() { }
    public void Method12() { }
    [BusinessMethod]
    public void Method13() { }
}
public class MyBusinessClass2
{
}
[BusinessClass]
public class MyBusinessClass3
{
    [BusinessMethod]
    public void Method31() { }
    public void Method32() { }
    [BusinessMethod]
    public void Method33() { }
}
```

**More information**

You may also find the following links useful:

- [PropertyGrid - Change items of a dropdown property editor based on another property value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65842530/3110834)
- [User Control Property that shows a list of all Forms at design time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58580911/3110834)
- [ITypeDiscoveryService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.itypediscoveryservice?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8): Discovers available types at design time.
- [ITypeResolutionService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.ityperesolutionservice?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8): Provides an interface to retrieve an assembly or type by name.
- [TypeConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8): Provides a unified way of converting types of values to other types, as well as for accessing standard values and subproperties.

Comment: I know the question is a bit old, but that would be nice if you can give it a try/verify it.